# App Facebook Login Integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am wondering if it is possible on an app I am creating that since it requires facebook login, if the user already has the facebook app installed and has logged in through the integrated facebook features with iOS, how can I grab the email and password provided there so that the user does not have to enter in the login info manually.  Is this possible just to take that login info?  Where can I look to achieve this?

Comment: Please refer [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login/)
Go through the entire document, all your queries have solutions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running >=ios6 there is an inbuilt integration with Facebook and Twitter and so if you're logged in from there, you can very easily take access permission from your app and you will be good to go.

So access facebook like this:

```
 // Request access to the Facebook accounts
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
        if (granted) {//granted facebook account access
            NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
            // Check if there's at least one facebook account
            if (accounts.count > 0){
ACAccount *fbAccount = [accounts objectAtIndex:0];
    //perform your stuff
    //get facebook timeline, post etc.
    }
    }];
```

And yes if you intend to get the username, email you can't just get that by some method. You'll have to explicitly ask for email and other user profile information through a call to facebook. Password are never accessible.

Answer (score 0):

For starters facebook won't just give you a users email and password, you have to ask for their email and they would NEVER give you their password. What Facebook does is provide you with an access_token once a user has authorised your app and this in effect logs them in. But please note, they won't just log a user into your app (even if facebook is on the phone) as you must still ask the user to authorise your app.

I'd suggest you take a look at the Facebook developer site specifically

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/

which walks you through a sample Facebook intergrated iOS app there is a specific section on authentication

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/

Then if you get stuck on specific areas, ask another more detailed question here with code snippets.

best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Use the Facebook sdk in your application.  You will not be able to 'grab' the username and password.  The authentication will give you a 'yes' or 'no'.  Here is an example from Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/

You will need to register your app through Facebook to get a developer id.